# View of file entities, sorted by upload date, reorders when updating a file

Tags: views, files

I have a view of file entities, sorted by **upload** date. When I edit one of the fields attached to one of my files the upload date of the file gets updated. The view now shows the last *modified* file first and no longer the last *uploaded*. Is this the normal behavior? Is there a way to actually sort my view by *upload* date?

Answer (score 1):

A quick check with `drupal_get_schema()` confirms that file entities have only one associated time column called `timestamp`; there is no separate "upload" and "modified" date. So that timestamp, presumably, gets updated every time the file entity gets saved.

This makes sense from a certain standpoint because editing a file entity could involve updating the file itself.

I decided to take a crack at a custom module that would add a new "upload date" column to the file entity table. This may be completely wrong, and I haven't tested it, so do NOT try to use it on a production website until you're sure it works, but it might just give you what you're looking for.

In `mymodule.install`:

```
function mymodule_install() {
  // Add a column to the file table for your new creation date field.
  db_add_field('file_managed', 'upload_date', array(
    'type' => 'int',
    'unsigned' => TRUE,
    'not null' => TRUE,
    'default' => 0
  ));
  // Load all existing files and set their upload date to be equal to their current timestamp.
  $files = entity_load($file);
  foreach($files as $file) {
    $file->upload_date = $file->timestamp;
    file_save($file);
  }
}
// Drop the new field if the module is uninstalled.
function mymodule_uninstall() {
  db_drop_field('file_managed', 'upload_date');
}
```

In `mymodule.module`:

```
// Set the upload time field to the current time when the file is first saved
function mymodule_file_presave($file) {
  if(!isset($file->upload_date) || $file->upload_date == 0) {
    $file->created_date = time();
  }
}
// @TODO make the upload date field editable.
```

In `mymodule.views.inc`:

```
// Add a field handler for your new field.
function mymodule_views_data_alter(&$data) {
  $data['file']['upload_date'] = array(
    'title' => t("Upload date"),
    'help'  => t("The date the file was first uploaded."),
    'field' => array(
      'handler' => 'views_handler_field_date',
    ),
  );
}
```

Assuming that I didn't screw up, once the module is installed you'll need to add the upload date field to your view and use it for sorting.

Comment: Thanks for the info! Is there an advantage of this approach over just adding another field 'field_upload_time' and populating it upon upload but not making it accessible afterwards? I could then certainly sort the view by this new field.

Comment: @deinqwertz You know, probably not, apart from the automation, which you could potentially do with a field anyway. It's probably slightly more lightweight than a field and it brings the file entity schema more inline with that of other entities, like nodes, that have a separate "created" and "changed" column out-of-the-box, but as for being simplest to implement, you have me beat with the obvious.